# Not able open open applications in iPhone SDK 3.2

Tags: iphone, sdk, xcode3.2

Hi guys i have downloaded iPhone SDK 3.2 and installed it successfully, after that i shutdown the system and restart it. When i am opening previous applications or try to create new application i am getting "Not Responding". What may be the problem can any one help me out.

Comment: If you are encountering bugs with the new SDK, be sure to report them at http://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone SDK 3.2 is still under NDA. Therefore, you are not allowed to ask related questions. Please try submitting your question to Apple Developer Forums.